# Update Google Doc Files With Data Pulled From a SpreadSheet Using Doc File Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I need to assign a membership number to each request I receive from aspiring members of my association.

Aspiring members fill a Google Docs file. When their requests are validated, those files need to be updated with the assigned membership number.

Inside the spreadsheet I have two columns. One contains the **membership number** and the other contains the **ID of the request**.

[Spreadsheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7JUa.png)

The **doc files are named with the ID of the request** as well. The membership numbers should be added in place of the placeholder {membershipnumber} found in the doc files.

[Doc File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viP0e.png)

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks a lot for your precious help!

I really have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue of your script. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script? And, can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks a lot for your help. I am very new to programming and I currently have no script for this issue. I need to write a script from scratch. You already helped me in the past and it has been very precious!

Comment: @Tanaike the idea is the following.

Doc files are stored in a specific folder.
Each file is named with the ID of the request.
Inside the spreadsheet I have a column for the ID and a column for the Membership Number.
I want to add the Membership Number inside the corresponding Google Docs file.
The Membership Number should replace the placeholder {membershipnumber} inside the Doc file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have Google Document files in the specific folder and have a Google Spreadsheet including the values for updating the Google Document files.
- You want to replace the value of `{membershipnumber}` with the values of column "A" by searching the filename using the value of column "C".

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set the variables. And, save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID of the folder including the Google Document files.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const obj = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [a, , c]) => (o[c] = a.trim(), o), {});
  const docs = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (docs.hasNext()) {
    const file = docs.next();
    const filename = file.getName().trim();
    if (obj[filename]) {
      const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
      doc.getBody().replaceText("{membershipnumber}", obj[filename]);
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the Google Document files are updated using the values of column "A" by searching the Document files with the filename retrieved from column "C".

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByType(String))
- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)

Comment: thanks a lot for your precious help. Your script works as a dream! @Tanaike

Comment: @alecanc Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.